# Bash wait for process start

Tags: bash, loops, conditional-statements

I'm trying to say to Bash , wait for a Process Start / Begin. I'm trying by this way for example:

```
notepad=`pidof notepad.exe`
    until [ $notepad > 0 ]
        do
            taskset -p 03 $notepad
            renice -n 5 -p $notepad
            sleep 5
            renice -n 0 -p $notepad
        done
```

well i have the follow questions:

1. why this generate a file called “0″ (the file are empty)
    i dont wanna make a new file , just wait for the PID to check execution.
2. This is a Loop , but if the 2 commands are execute correclty , 1 time
    how i can continue to done ???
3. For this its better use "until or while" ???
4. Another ideas for wait Process Start or Begin ???

Answer (score 26):

There are multiple issues with your code:

1. pidof doesn't print 0 or -1 if there's no process, so your logic is wrong
2. pidof can return multiple pids if there are multiple processes, which would break your comparison
3. `>` has to be escaped in `[ ]` otherwise your code is equivalent to `[ $notepad ] > 0`, directing to a file.
4. `>` isn't even the right operator. You wanted `-gt`, but as mentioned in point #1 and #2, you shouldn't compare numbers.
5. `until` runs the loop until the condition is true. it doesn't wait for the condition to become true, and then run the loop.

This is how you should do it:

```
# Wait for notepad to start
until pids=$(pidof notepad)
do   
    sleep 1
done

# Notepad has now started.

# There could be multiple notepad processes, so loop over the pids
for pid in $pids
do        
    taskset -p 03 $pid
    renice -n 5 -p $pid
    sleep 5
    renice -n 0 -p $pid
done

# The notepad process(es) have now been handled
```

Comment: you can explain me or give a link with explication how how thats line

1 - pids=(pidof notepads) 
ok the variable pids=Some Entire Number

2 - for pid in $pids
why pid ? in $pids are the variable , but i dont undertand the "pid" this is making a new varible ???

Comment: `pids=$(pidof notepad)` becomes `pids="14436 16690 19023"` (or maybe just `pids="14436"` if there is only one running notepad). With the for loop, you loop over each of these numbers in `$pids`. Each time the loop runs, `$pid` will be a different value from the list in `$pids`, so the first time it will be 14436, next time 16690, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your first question: '>' is not the mathematical/comparison operator 'greater than'; it's bash's way of letting you pipe output to a file (handle).

```
echo "some text" > myfile.txt
```

will create a file named myfile.txt, and '>' sent the output of the command into that file. I would imagine that your file '0' has the pid in it, and nothing else.

Instead, try `-gt` (or related variants: `-ge`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-eg`, `-ne`) to test if one value is greater than (or: greater than or equal, less than, less than or equal, equal, not equal, respectively) to see if that helps. That is,

```
until [ $notepad -gt 0 ]
```

Comment: `>` writes to a file. If the file exists, it is overwritten. `>>` appends to the end of a file; if the file does not already exist, it is created. `>` can delete data, `>>` does not.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to wait until notepad is launched. Then the pidof must be inside your loop.

```
while ! pidof notepad.exe >> /dev/null ;
do
sleep 1
done
notepad=$(pidof notepad.exe)
taskset -p 03 $notepad
renice -n 5 -p $notepad
sleep 5
renice -n 0 -p $notepad
```

Comment: Well the idea , really its , when the taskset & renice , are apply , exit the loop to continue with the script.

I dont know if good idea use break or continue for that.