# Service started from Init.rc

Tags: android, boot

I want to call a script from my `init.rc`:

```
service script /system/etc/wifi.sh
    user system
    group wifi
    class main
    oneshot
```

Content of `wifi.sh`:

```
#!/system/bin/sh

service p2p_supplicant /system/bin/wpa_supplicant \
    -iwlan0 -Dnl80211 -c/data/misc/wifi/wpa_supplicant.conf
    class late_start
    disabled
    oneshot
```

But `p2p_supplicant` service is not started.

Is it possible to call service from another service?

Comment: Elaborate your question more clearly so it'll get more attention

Comment: I want to create on file /system/etc/wifi.sh, Which have configuration parameter for wifi module. I want to call this /system/etc/wifi.sh from init.rc.  I can create directory but i can not start service from /system/etc/wifi.sh

Answer (score 0):

You could have your bash script wait for the desired process to start running before it does anything. See this article for information: [Bash wait for process start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326245/bash-wait-for-process-start)

In your specific case it seems like there is a better way to configure the supplicant using parameters and the conf file that doesn't involve running a shell script.