# How can I start Thunderbird and minimize the window on startup in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, startup

I'm trying to have Thunderbird open on startup and have its window hidden or minimized. I have been able to accomplish this with some other applications, but Thunderbird doesn't seem to have any handy options for opening into the tray or minimized.

I've written a bash script and included it in the Startup gui. This script is largely based off of what I read here: [Bash wait for process start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19326245/bash-wait-for-process-start). And here is my script:

```
#! /bin/bash

thunderbird &
while pids=$(pidof thunderbird)
do
    sleep 1s
done
sleep 3s
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class thunderbird windowminimize
```

I also tried without the "&" in `thunderbird &` and I tried without the `while` loop and instead having a very long `sleep` wait. If I run a script with the following lines within the terminal (not at startup), it works just fine:

```
thunderbird &
sleep 3s
xdotool search --onlyvisible --class thunderbird windowminimize
```

Am I doing something wrong with the loop? Or is there something with the startup process that makes this not work? I also have other applications starting up, but I don't think those would interfere with this. I'm pretty new to Linux.

Comment: SO is only for programming questions. For questions about using Ubuntu, ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, or more generally [unix.se] or [su].

Comment: Oh wait, did you mean to write `while` instead of `until`?

Comment: @wjandrea I assumed this was programming related since I'm trying to make a bash script. The answer that I linked to uses `while`, but I just tried `until` and it still doesn't minimize the window.

Comment: Fair enough, it is about programming in that repect. But the script itself looks fine if you switch `while` for `until`, so I'm thinking the problem is Ubuntu-specific, so I still recommend posting on [ubuntu.se] instead. Scripting is on-topic there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just copy pasting [this ask ubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/870338):

I achieved the desired behaviour in the following way:

**1)** Install `alltray` which provides an easy method to open Thunderbird at startup:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install alltray
```

**2)** Add to Startup Applications:

[image: Startup Applications]

This will open Thunderbird at startup but it will not be minimised.

**----- UPDATE** `Minimize on Start and Close` **IS NO LONGER SUPPORTED -----**

<s>**3)** Then install `Minimize on Start and Close` in Thunderbird (Tools->Add-ons->Get Add-ons)</s>

This needs to be configured (Tools->Add-ons->Extensions->Preferences) as follows:

[image: Add-on Config]

**--------------------------------------------------**

**3)** Then install `Keep in Taskbar` and restart Thunderbird.

This is a combination of previous suggestions from various locations that works in Ubuntu 16.04.

**I thought I would share this to provide an easy, updated method for others.**

Comment: Does alltray work with Ubuntu 20.04? I get this error when I enter `alltray thunderbird` in the terminal: `Gtk-Message: 21:03:43.640: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"

Alltray: no system tray/notification area found.
I will wait..... I have time....

In the meantime you may add a system tray applet
to the panel.`  Anyway, I'd prefer to have the window minimized rather than hidden in the tray.

Comment: not sure @MikenIke , I just know that you can install alltray (because I tried to install it with docker) but I'm not able to say more than that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/663187/how-can-i-run-a-program-on-startup-minimized). I just copied and pasted the answer's second python script.

Answer (score 0):

Install xdotool `sudo apt install xdotool`

Create a file, I like it to be in PATH, e.g. `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/startup-thunderbird` with (Ctrl-Shift-V to paste in terminal):

```
#!/bin/bash
thunderbird &
while true; do
    sleep 1
    w=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --name "Mozilla Thunderbird")
    if [ ! -z $w ]; then
        echo "minimizing $w"
        xdotool windowminimize $w
        break
    fi
done
```

Save it then make it executable `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/startup-thunderbird`

Add `startup-thunderbird` to the commands in Startup Applications.

Comment: `while [ 1 ]` works, but not for the reasons you'd hope - `[ 0 ]` or `[ false ]` would also do the same thing; `[` checks if its argument is not the empty string. The idiomatic  endless loop is written simply `while true`.